# string.Concat, Mutable or Immutable?

Tags: c#

As I know string are immutable in C# unless StringBuilder class is used. The situation is, I have an ObjectResult(which implements IEnumerable) of string and I want to convert it to one single string object. There are two options here:

1. using string.Concat

   ```
   var myDesiredData = string.Concat(TheObjectResult)
   ```
2. using StringBuilder

   ```
   var sb = new StringBuiler();
   foreach (var item in TheObjectResult)
   {
     sb.Append(item);
   }
   var myDesiredData = sb.ToString();
   ```

I'm not sure how the first option is working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both options are almost identical. This is how `string.Concat(IEnumerable<string>)` is implemented:

```
[ComVisible(false)]
public static String Concat(IEnumerable<String> values) {
    if (values == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("values");
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<String>() != null);
    Contract.EndContractBlock();

    StringBuilder result = StringBuilderCache.Acquire();
    using(IEnumerator<String> en = values.GetEnumerator()) {
        while (en.MoveNext()) {
            if (en.Current != null) {
                result.Append(en.Current);
            }
        }            
    }
    return StringBuilderCache.GetStringAndRelease(result);            
}
```

I would go with `string.Concat`, because why write a method that already exists.

Comment: There is also a reference/example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.string.concat?view=netframework-4.7#System_String_Concat__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__). For a more complex object than a list of strings you need to override `ToString()`